# Python is not installed and The terminal shell path "cmd.exe" does not exist

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

Python is not installed and The terminal shell path "cmd.exe" does not exist. (+select python interpreter, as an addition to the first mistake)
This 2 errors appeared in my vscode...Could somebody help me, please. I am desperate…

First things first:
I have already worked in python using pycharm and vscode. Then by mistake I made some incorrect changes in the path variable. After that everything stopped working.

Things that I have already tried so far
-> complete deletion of python and vscode and reinstallation both of it; 
-> using anaconda; working with paths, made changes like / -> \ -> and vice versa; 
-> When i installed python and the VScode editior, i checked the box on the first window asking to add to the path.
Nothing worked…

My path variable values are:

(Path for user): 

C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/;C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin; C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe; C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe; C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe;

(Path variable values for System):
C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe; C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe;C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin
I crave for all advices, you can share with!

I would like to work out with my paths again. For it, I ask somebody who also works in Windows, to copy his/her paths and send it to me. I will try to find mistakes or missing stuffs. If it is also doesn't work…Well, I have no idea. I will thankfully read all your advises. Looking forward for your answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you specified the path to specific files in your `PATH` variable. Instead, change those to point to the directories where those files exist.